# Safe parking in the centre of Mexico City

Tags: budget, safety, automobiles, mexico-city

Me and my friends are travelling to Mexico City with our own car. We found out it is almost impossible to park our car close to our hotel.

We are staying in Mexico City center:
República de Brasil 8, Centro, Cuauhtémoc, 06010 Ciudad de México, D.F.
Reasonable price would be maximum 300 pesos per 24 hours.

Can you help me where to park our car for 4-5 days safely and for reasonable price? Is it safe to park somewhere on the street in city center?

Comment: Ah Mexico City, the [27th largest city IN THE WORLD by land area](http://www.citymayors.com/statistics/largest-cities-area-125.html).  Perhaps you could mention which hotel, or where on earth it is in the city? And what's a 'reasonable price'?

Answer (score 1):

[Parkopedia shows a bunch of public parkings around the address you provided](http://en.parkopedia.mx/parking/rep%C3%BAblica_de_brasil_8_centro_cuauht%C3%A9moc_mexico_city_mexico/) (prices are in local currency `MXN`). Indeed, parking seems to a be a profitable business in Mexico City. The ones showing prices on them have been reviewed by community members, whilst the greyed-out ones have not. In my opinion a safe parking is one that is underground/off-the-street, manned possibly 24h or at least during the daytime.

With these constraints, and your 300`MXN` budget in mind you can see that one parking seem to fit your requirements: [Hermano Arolas Joséfina at 224`MXN` per 24h](http://en.parkopedia.mx/parking/carpark/hermano_arolas_jos%C3%A9fina/06000/ciudad_de_m%C3%A9xico/). There's also [Isabel la Catolica at 300`MXN` per 24h](http://en.parkopedia.mx/parking/carpark/isabel_la_cat%C3%B3lica_38/06000/ciudad_de_m%C3%A9xico/), but I couldn't understand from the description if it is indeed an underground/off-the-street parking.